# ngx-infinite-scroll event not being triggered when scroll is complete

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to implement infinite scroll using ngx-infinite-scroll in an angular 4 app but it its not being triggered. I read the documents and set the `height` of the element and set `scrollWindow` to false so that its triggered when the element is scrolled and not the entire page. However I can't get it to fire.

What am I doing worng?

I've created a [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/pyIFyBtRD9XfMpmsgc9C) to reproduce the issue

html

```
<div class="search-results"
     infinite-scroll
     [infiniteScrollDistance]="0.1"
     [infiniteScrollThrottle]="10"
     [scrollWindow]="false"
     (scrolled)="onScrollDown()">
  <p *ngFor="let i of is">
    {{i}}
  </p>
</div>
```

css

```
.search-results {
  height: 100px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

component

```
protected is = ['Item1', 'Item2', 'Item3'];

onScrolledDown() {
    console.log("scrolled");
}
```

Comment: I get this too, 3/4 times it fires, 1/4 time it doesn't.. I have height of the div set to 100% with overflow-y set to auto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using bootstrap 4 so you have to disable flex for it to work properly

```
.search-results {
  height: 100px;
  overflow: scroll;
  flex: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I have found a little workaround that fixes this issue by setting the infiniteScrollThrottle to 0, and make your own throttling method.

So here's how I did it:

in the HTML side, use these attributes:

```
[infiniteScrollThrottle]="0"
(scrolled)="loadMore()"
```

on the other hand, in the ts file, make your own throttling condition in the loadMore() function:

```
loading = false;
loadingThrottle = 300;

loadMore() {
    if (!this.loading) {
      this.loading = true;

      window.setTimeout(() => {

        // your loading logic here..

        this.loading = false;
      }, this.loadingThrottle);
   }
}
```